# GridView - TemplateField - HeaderTemplate - align right not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to set the header Text alignment to Right. (Data value is set to right (text-align:right;) properly, however I tried all the possible ways to set HeaderTemplate, but no luck for GridView, any hints what should I use here?

$' style="width: 50px; text-align:right;">
                            
                            
                                $' style="width: 50px; text-align:right;">

Comment: You can find plenty of Table formatting techniques here; http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/262546/HTML-Tables-formating-best-practices. If you want more specific answer, please add code snippet to your post so we could help. Regards,

Comment: I can not post the code, some reason it's truncating. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below link- Maintain all properties like align,bg-color..etc by using css is good practice

[How to Style a GridView with CSS in ASP.NET 4.0](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/themes/style-gridview-css/)

Comment: If you add align for individual templefield add <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />

Comment: Adhik, tried that but it's not working on GridView for one of the column. Some columns I show number, that should be right justified. Rest of the columns are left justified (works on data fields, bit not on header)